# How can I install new boot splash theme into Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, login-screen

I want to change my splash screen. But when I download any splash screen to my computer, I cannot install them. Every time, the computer gives me the same warning "that packet is not a format wanted" -warning like this-

I am asking "is there any other way to install splash screens?".

Note: I have also used 'Art manager' but it did not work properly.

Comment: Which splash screen are you referring to? The one that shows while the system is booting up is called `usplash`, while the one seen when logging in is related to `gnome`. A good place to find gnome splash screens is http://gnome-look.org/ though I don't know of any other ways to install splash screens short of rebuilding the archive in the right format.

Comment: Are you referring to wallpaper?

Comment: @Darth: the Ubuntu login screen is provided by GDM; most GDM themes are for an older (Ubuntu 9.04 or earlier) version of GDM, and won't work with the versions included in Ubuntu 9.10 and later.  also, Ubuntu 10.04 and later use `plymouth` instead of `usplash` for the boot-up splash screen (but i think you're correct that usplash was used in Ubuntu 9.10).

Comment: @quack quixote Thanks, I haven't used ubuntu since version 8 or so.

Comment: exept for wallpaper , I cannot install usplash and logging splash into my computer.I download some of packet from gnome-look.org,then I tried to install but  I failed.ever time I see same warning

Comment: @gcc: i've rolled back your title edit & rant; please don't deface the question like that.  you will need to have some patience.  try responding to the questions @Darth Android asked -- like clarifying which splash screen you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry Quack I also edited it. Just roll it back to yours. Sorry.

Comment: @shiki: it's fine, your edit actually made improvements. thanks.

Comment: @gcc: yeah, sometimes people downvote for no apparent reason.  don't take it personally.

Comment: @gcc - Here you go with +1 vote. But please, don't use this language, and don't say "they don't know nothing". If you don't respect others... what do you want in exchange? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's clear this up. First, please edit your question or do something about that mentality. If you ask it like this, people are not stupid, they just don't tend to answer rude questions. (Sorry if you asked it like this only here.)

---

For Ubuntu **9.10**:
It's really easy. Just follow the step-by-step instruction on the following page:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7939/how-to-change-xsplash-themes-in-ubuntu-9.10/

---

This is for **10.04**:

Installing a splash in Ubuntu/Linux is not easy. It never was. Ubuntu used `usplash`, but they migrated to `plymouth` in version of 10.04 (just like Quack Quixote said).

About installing themes for Plymouth (guess you don't want to mess up plymouth):
http://crashsystems.net/2010/04/changing-plymouth-themes/

How can you use `usplash`? Try removing `plymouth` package in Synaptic and see what happens. (Seriously, I never tried, I simply disable it.) If you succeed, you only have to install `usplash` package from Synaptic after this. Then, do as the gnome-look.org instructions tells you (usually you can find an INSTALL, README file inside the packages).

---

For Ubuntu **<=9.04**:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=344033
http://geekybits.blogspot.com/2007/11/installing-new-usplash-themes-in-ubuntu.html
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Change-Ubuntu-Bootsplash-Theme-55237.shtml
http://www.troublenow.org/archives/16

Basically open a terminal from Appliactions and type:
`uname -r`
`sudo update-alternatives --config usplash-artwork.so`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-"name-of-your-kernel-here` (what you saw at the `uname -r` command)

(Fix me, it may work that you type: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-${uname -r}`

---

Comment: OP is using Ubuntu 9.10; i mentioned 10.04 because it's what i use and am familiar with.  (i used 9.04 a little, and largely skipped 9.10, so i wasn't sure what bootsplash 9.10 was using.  which one used `splashy`? or am i misremembering?)

Comment: Oh my gosh. Really. They used 3 types of boot screen! First, USplash, second, xSplash, and now, Plymouth. Geez. Okay, adding additional info. :) | Don't know why they didnt use Plymouth at first.. ehh. | Used all of the Ubuntu versions so far but I always disable them..thats why it was not noticeable.